# Can we display discontinued products in website?

Tags: products, sku, magento2.4.1, icon

Can we display discontinued sku?

I have a some SKU’s in my website, but after some time it's discontinued, but people still search for it. I've seen this feature in many websites showing discontinued products after all the other products with an icon like the Sale tag on top of the picture.
Can we to do this?

Comment: You can create an attribute like discontinue with YES/NO values. assign YES to discontinue product and move them to bottom.for moving you can refer https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/magento-2-display-out-of-stock-products-at-the-end-of-the-list-page/

Comment: Discontinued product : can we display discontinued icon then customer know the status of the product.